# How to pass variable inside JMESpath query?

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, jmespath

I am trying to pass an environment variable inside a JMESpath query for an az cli command. Currently the problem is when I am passing the variable at standalone, I am able to get the result as expected but when I using the same command inside a while or for loop, the value is passing as null. Kindly help me on this and appreciate your effort.
My script is as follows:

```
jq -c '.[]' 2data.json | while read i
do
echo "value of i is $i"
az postgres server firewall-rule show --ids $firewallName --query "[name == '$i'].{name:name}"
done
```

Output:

```
value of i is "secondrule"
{
  "name": null
}
value of i is "newRule"
{
  "name": null
}
```

2data.json file contains

```
[ "secondrule", "newRule" ]
```

Manual execution of az command:

```
data="secondrule"
az postgres server firewall-rule show --ids $firewallName --query "[?name == '$data'].{name:name}"
```

Output of manual execution: (expected)

```
[
  {
    "name": "secondrule"
  }
]
```

How I can resolve this and pass the input as variable and get the desired output?

Comment: Without a hint of the JSON structure that resides in _2data.json_, that would be hard to answer. Please consider [edit]ing this in your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. 2data.json is the json file structure which I was trying to parse. I found another way to parse my result and got the desired output